# .htaccess and rewrite of URL

Tags: jsp, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Need help with .htaccess - not able to get what i want...

**Ugly URL -** http://www.onnlist.com/punerealestate.jsp?section=realestate&file=pune

**Want Better URL (such as) -** mysite/realestate/pune/punerealestate.html

here is my latest **.htacess file** - of course this does not work -

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+).html /punerealestate.jsp?section=$1&file=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^aboutus.jsp/$ /pages/about.html [L]
```

**Edit:** I just tried Fabian's solution.  I copied the 3 lines into the .htaccess file in the root directory of my website but it is still not working.  Any ideas?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what is "not working."  What URL are you testing with?

Comment: testing with following URL - http://www.onnlist.com/punerealestate.jsp?section=realestate&file=pune    

basically when i drop the .htaccess under root i expected URL will change to deep directory structure

Answer (score 0):

The following example will rewrite
**http://www.onnlist.com/bla1/bla2/punerealestate.html**
to
**http://www.onnlist.com/punerealestate.jsp?section=bla1&file=bla2**

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/punerealestate.html /punerealestate.jsp?section=$1&file=$2 [L]
```